# how to use combination of alert msg and response.redirect in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I want to use the combination of alert box msg and also the response.redirect in ASP language. As my below code doesn't work. 
Please help, Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript">
     <!--
     window.alert ("Please choose another Type of Redemption");
     //-->
</script>

<% Response.Redirect("redeem_type.asp?cardno="&BlinkCard&" ") %>
```

Comment: Your javascript runs on the client and Response.Redirect runs on the server. Try `window.location.href = "redeem_type.asp?cardno=" + <%=this.BlinkCard%>`

Comment: Nice.. Good to know...:)

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect` commands are used to send the user to another URL instead of the page they have landed on, without sending any HTML content.

You need to put your URL into something like a button, so the user sees your first message and then clicks "Next" or something that will then take them to the page you want to send them to.

Comment: Assuming you want them to see your message before going to the other page, of course.